# Use values of a vector in row names in R?

Tags: r, names

I have a numeric vector `vec <- c(1.5,1.3,5.7)`, a vector of Greek letters `Greeks <- c("$\\alpha$","$\\beta$","$\\gamma$")`, and a matrix `M<-diag(3)`. I want to assign names to this table using latex symbols and the values of `vec`. Basically, I want to get:

```
vec <- c(1.5,1.3,5.7)
M<-diag(3)
rnames <- c("$\\alpha$ (1.5)","$\\beta$ (1.3)","$\\gamma$ (5.7)")
rownames(M) <- rnames
```

In my real case scenario, vec is of variable length, and longer than 3. So, I would like to call `vec` and `Greeks` in an automatic way. I would appreciate any hints.

The reason for this is because I will then `xtable(M)` to put it in my latex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it rigth, you can just use paste0 to generate the names

```
vec <- c(1.5,1.3,5.7)
M<-diag(3)
Greeks <- c("$\\alpha$","$\\beta$","$\\gamma$")

rnames <- paste0(Greeks, " (", vec, ")")

rownames(M) <- rnames

rownames(M)

> [1] "$\\alpha$ (1.5)" "$\\beta$ (1.3)"  "$\\gamma$ (5.7)"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for (will accept in 5 minutes).